# Determining GPS point from line coordinates

Tags: line, coordinates, convert

[image]I have an older survey with what I am calling line coordinates.  I am trying to determine the standard GPS coordinates for two intersecting lines.  An example of the survey format are these intersection coordinates:   N41(degrees) 18'27"W   and   N33(degrees) 52'16"E

What is the method to determine the standard GPS coordinates for the point of intersection?

Comment: Gonna need more information. What program are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: the line coordinates are on paper copy of old survey.  I'm looking for point coordinates i can use in a hand held GPS device.  I don't have nor aware of a tool to make the translation.

Comment: In addition to line bearings, you need start points. Are the start points in projected coordinates or latitudes and longitudes? Some GPS devices can do intersection problems.

Comment: Please post your paper survey. Let's see what you've got.

Comment: Survey posted.  I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for posting your survey map. There are no starting coordinates, and not even a mention of city or county, so I'm afraid you're out of luck. If you know what county this is in you can search for parcel data, and in GIS software, like QGIS, you can get Lats and Longs of parcel corners.